# Angular 2 capture button attribute on click

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular-cli

I have a simple array that I'm looping through and outputting as buttons.

I'm adding the loop index as an attribute on the buttons

How do I get the button attribute when its clicked.

```
    // component
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })

    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!';

      blocks: string[] = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','White'];

      constructor(){}

      clickEvent($event){
        alert($event.target.attr.data-index);
      }

    }




    // component.html
    <div class="blocks">

      <div *ngFor="let block of blocks; let i=index">
        <button (click)="clickEvent($event)" [attr.data-index]="i">{{block}}</button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to assign and then read from the attribute. You can use   the value directly

```
(click)="clickEvent(i)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMStringMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap) accessible through [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) property to get data attributes value:

```
clickEvent($event){
    alert($event.target.dataset.index);
}
```

Or standard [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method:

```
clickEvent($event){
    alert($event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
}
```

Here is the quote from the the docs:

> Reading the values of these attributes out in JavaScript is also very
>   simple. You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read
>   them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can
>   read out via a dataset property.
>
> To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property
>   by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are
>   converted to camelCase).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the current item from the array, you can just send it to the click handler:

```
<button (click)="clickEvent($event, block)">{{block}}</button>
```

```
clickEvent($event, block) {
  alert(block);
}
```